# How do I approach finding the inverse of this function?

Tags: r

I'm reading a paper by Steve Horvath (2013) for the epigenetic clock he developed. He used an age calibration function before carrying out an elastic net regression analysis. The function F for transforming age is as follows (adult age = 20):

> F(age)=log(age+1)-log(adult.age+1) if age<= adult.age
>
> F(age)=(age-adult.age)/(adult.age+1) if age> adult.age

Using R, I have written the function as follows:

```
ageC <- function(age) {
  if (age <= 20) {
    ageC = log(age+1)-log(21)}
  if (age > 20) {
    ageC = (age-20)/(21)
  }
  return(ageC)
}
```

My question is how do I find the inverse of the function F? The model predicts DNA methylation age (DNAmAge) using the following:

> DNAmAge = inverse.F(b0 + b1CpG1 + . . . + b353CpG353)

What is the "inverse.F" portion?

Comment: Do you want a closed form solution or any inverse will do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For brevity, let $x_0$ be the adult-age and let $x$ be the age (I will assume that the age is non-negative and adult-age is positive).  Your function of interest $F: \mathbb{R}_{0+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is given by:

$$\begin{align}
F(x) 
&= \int \limits_{x_0}^x \frac{ds}{\min(s,x_0)+1} \\[6pt]
&= \begin{cases}
\log(x+1) - \log(x_0+1) & & \text{for } 0 \leqslant x \leqslant x_0, \\[6pt]
(x-x_0)/(x_0+1) & & \text{for } x > x_0. \\[6pt]
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

This function has first derivative $F'(x) = 1/(\min(x,x_0)+1)$ so it is strictly increasing and has an inverse.  (It is also simple to show that this is a continuous function, so its inverse is also continuous.)  For this part I will use $r=F(x)$ to represent the age-calibration.  Solving for $x$ using some simple algebra on each part gives the corresponding inverse function $F^{-1}: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{0+}$, which is:

$$F^{-1}(r) = 
\begin{cases}
(x_0+1) \exp(r) - 1 & & \text{for } r \leqslant 0, \\[6pt]
x_0 + r(x_0+1) & & \text{for } r > 0. \\[6pt]
\end{cases}$$

---

**Computation in R:** It would be preferable to program these functions without hard-coding the adult-age you wish to use.  If you really want to get fancy then you can also add the derivatives to the functions as `gradient` and `hessian` attributes, which is useful if you use these functions later in optimisation work.  You can program these functions in `R` as follows:

```
ageC <- function(age, age.adult, gradient = FALSE, hessian = FALSE) {
  if (age < 0)          stop('Error: Input age must be non-negative')
  if (age.adult <= 0)   stop('Error: Input age.adult must be positive')
  if (age <= age.adult) { OUT <- log((age+1)/(age.adult+1)) }
  if (age > age.adult)  { OUT <- (age-age.adult)/(age.adult+1) }
  if (gradient) {
    attr(OUT, 'gradient') <- 1/(min(age, age.adult)+1) }
  if (hessian)  {
    attr(OUT, 'hessian')  <- ifelse(age < age.adult, -1/(age+1)^2, 0) }
  OUT }

ageC.inverse <- function(r, age.adult, gradient = FALSE, hessian = FALSE) {
  if (age.adult <= 0)   stop('Error: Input age.adult must be positive')
  if (r <= 0) { OUT <- (age.adult+1)*exp(r) - 1 }
  if (r > 0)  { OUT <- age.adult + r*(age.adult+1) }
  if (gradient) {
    attr(OUT, 'gradient') <- ifelse(r < 0, (age.adult+1)*exp(r), age.adult) }
  if (hessian)  {
    attr(OUT, 'hessian')  <- ifelse(r < 0, (age.adult+1)*exp(r), 0) }
  OUT }
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to find a quick solution about the inverse of the function $f$ just define an interpolation functions $g$ such that $g(f(x))=x$.

Here is a quick example doing that in R:

```
ageC <- function(age) {
  if (age <= 20) {
    ageC = log(age+1)-log(21)}
  if (age > 20) {
    ageC = (age-20)/(21)
  }
  return(ageC)
}

mydf = data.frame(
  ages = seq(0,100, by=0.05)
)

mydf$agesC = sapply(mydf$ages, ageC)

inv_ages = approxfun(x=mydf$agesC, y=mydf$ages) # the function g

# Quick check it works
q_age = 42.1
all.equal(q_age, inv_ages(ageC(q_age))) # Yep, TRUE
```